# Symfony update with javascript(Ajax)

Tags: symfony, twig

In my project, I have a select box in my table who should update the object in database on select box value change, I made like this, and I get the value of select option selected and the id who should be updated, the problem is the value in the database is not modified, 
my controller

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Client $client)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($client);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ClientType', $client);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $status = $request->request->get('status');
        $client->setStatus($status);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('client_index');
    }

    return $this->render('client/edit.html.twig', array(
        'client' => $client,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

In my js

```
function update(id, status){
var statusValue = {'status':status};
var path = Routing.generate('client_edit',{'id': id});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path,
    data: statusValue
});
```

}

in my table in client index

```
<td>
<select id="status" name="status" onchange="update({{ client.id }}, this.value)">
    <option {% if client.status is empty %}
    selected
    {% endif %}>Status</option>

    <option {% if client.status == 'Envoyer') %}
        selected
    {% endif %}
            value="Envoyer">Envoyer</option>
    <option {% if client.status == 'Annuler') %}
        selected
    {% endif %}
            value="Annuler">Annuler</option>
    <option {% if client.status == 'Rejetter') %}
        selected
    {% endif %}
            value="Rejeter">Rejeter</option>
</select>
```

So here, I get the id and the value of select option selected but nothing is updated in my database, who can perform it to update the of my database, thanks!

Comment: ->persist($client); and then ->flush()?

Comment: ok thanks, but nothing change!

Comment: so does your code pass the isValid check? I.e. does your form contain some other fields (as you are not passing anything else to the ajax request) which might cause the form/entity validation to fail?

Comment: I don't know, I've just pass the status in the ajax! and how can I solve the validation fail?

Answer (score 1):

The problem come from this line

```
$editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()
```

Because your form is never submitted.
If you don't need form validation replace this line by this :

```
//Check if it's an ajax request
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
//you can get status directly with this
$request->get('status');
//Do some stuff...
```